# Get the details of a related object from before returning to client

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am saving an object in my database, it stores the ID which relates to an object stored in another table. When I retrieve this from the database, I want to return the details of this class to the client along with the name of the related object. ie,

AntifungalAgent

```
ID: 1
Name: "Drug1"
```

InteractingDrug

```
ID: 1
Name: "Drug2"
```

Interaction

```
ID: 1
AntifungalID: 1
InteractingDrugID: 1
```

When I retrieve the data for the Interaction from my controller, the `ID` is the `ID` of the `interactingDrug` so it returns all interactions with that interacting drug.

```cs
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<DrugInteractions>>> getInteraction(int id)
{
    return await _context.DrugInteractions
                         .Include(di => di.InteractingDrug)
                         .Include(di => di.AntifungalAgent)
                         .Where(di => di.InteractingDrug.ID == id)
                         .ToListAsync();
}
```

Currently, I get a list of all the interactions as expected. But I only get a number for the `antifungalAgentID` and the `InteractingDrugID`.

I want to also get the name of these 2 drugs.

I have created a `DrugInteractionDto` class.

```cs
public class DrugInteractionDTO
{
    public string Antifungal { get; set; }
    public string InteractingDrug { get; set; }
    public string BasicDetailedInformation { get; set; }
    public string ProDetailedInformation { get; set; }
    public Severity Severity { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

But I am stuck on adding the names of the `antifungalAgent` and `interactingDrug` to this DTO, so that I can return this to the client and use the names in the UI.

Comment: Can you show the `DrugInteraction` class? What is the relationship between `DrugInteraction` and `AntifungalAgent` and `InteractingDrug`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your provided data, the `DrugInteraction` is the associate table between `AntifungalAgent` and `InteractingDrug` tables.

> AntifungalAgent (1..m) --> DrugInteraction (m..1) <-- InteractingDrug

The generated `DrugInteraction` entity class should be looked as below:

```cs
public class DrugInteraction
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int AntifungalAgentID { get; set; }

    public int InteractingDrugID { get; set; }

    public virtual AntifungalAgent AntifungalAgent { get; set; }

    public virtual InteractingDrug InteractingDrug { get; set; }
}
```

You need the `.Select()` to transform the each object from `DrugInteractions` to `DrugInteractionDTO` type.

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult<List<DrugInteractionDTO>>> getInteraction(int id)
{
    return await _context.DrugInteractions
            .Include(di => di.InteractingDrug)
            .Include(di => di.AntifungalAgent)
            .Where(di => di.InteractingDrug.ID == id)
            .Select(x => new DrugInteractionDTO
            {
                Antifungal = x.AntifungalAgent.Name,
                InteractingDrug = x.InteractingDrug.Name,
                ID = x.ID,
                // Following properties
            })
            .ToListAsync();
}
```